# i am trying to load images from server in my android app using lazy image loader but it doesnt display

Tags: java, android, lazy-loading

i am trying to load images from server in my android app using lazy image loader but it doesn't display. Access the image URL through JSON and pass to Lazy Loader still it not work. plz give suggestion....

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category);

     grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);


        testAsynch mytest= new testAsynch();
        mytest.execute();
      //  adapter=new LazyAdapter(this,imgNames);
       // grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, mylist);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}


class testAsynch extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String> 
{
    String readFeed;
    JSONObject json;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    protected void onPreExecute(){

            Log.d("PreExceute","On pre Exceute......");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

        Log.d("DoINBackGround","On doInBackground...");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // domain intentionally obfuscated for security reasons
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://innobytes.in/webservices/category");
        //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/pratik/category");
        httpGet.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        try 
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("onProgressUpdate","Failed to download file..........");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();

    }




    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.
        String autcElement = null;
        String img;

        //String url="http://innobytes.in/artsgallery.in/productpic/";


                    try{
                        readFeed = result;


                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(readFeed);


                        System.out.println("OKAY_8!!");
                        //*********** Process each JSON Node ***********//*

                        int lengthJsonArr =jsonarray.length();

                        for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
                        {

                            System.out.println("OKAY_9!!");

                            autcElement = jsonarray.toString();
                            //name[i]=autcElement;
                            imgNames.add(autcElement);

                        //  bean.setMediaImageUrl(jsonarray.toString());
                            mylist.add(autcElement);
                        }



                        System.out.print(""+imgNames);

                    }                   
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        // Close progress dialog
    }


 }}
```

Comment: This is not right way to fetch data from server. Post your json data. Also set your adapter in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: Is your URL correct??

Comment: and you didnt notifyadapter _adapter = new adapter(this, arraylist);
                        gridview.setAdapter(_adapter);
                        _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi He did. but on onCreate() method.

Comment: if i write the same code in onpostexecute() it gives error to newLazyAdapter(this,arraylist);